# GridLayout: width and height issues

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a few questions about `GridLayout` in `QtQuickLayouts 1.3`:

1. How should I make it , so the GridLayout places into *CORRECT* row/column every element of my grid even if the size of the element is not clearly specified by `with` or `height` parameter?

Let me remove the `width` and `height` and I will show you the broken layout. I will just comment it out:

```
        Item {
            id: test_item  
            //Layout.fillWidth: true
            //height: 20
        }
```

Full source code of the `.qml` file is here, and can be tested with `bin/qmlscene`:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 500;

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        GridLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 2
            Label {
                text:"Email:"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 80; height: 20
                border.color: "magenta"
            }
            Label {
                text: "Full Name:"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            Item {
                id: test_item // the commented out portion, to show the flaw
                //Layout.fillWidth: true
                //height: 20
            }
            Label {
                text: "Gender:"
            }
            RowLayout {
                Layout.minimumHeight: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                RadioButton {
                    text: "Male"
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: 20
                }
                RadioButton {
                    text: "Female"
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: 20
                }
            }
            Label {
                text: "Mobile phone:"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 80; height: 20
                border.color: "magenta"
            }
        }
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "Cancel"
            }
            Button {
                text: " Ok "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The 'broken` output looks like this:

[image: Broken layout due to missing Item size]

While the correct output , with `Item`'s size specified looks like this:

[image: Correct GridLayout]

2) The second question. How do I load a component into a `GridLayout` cell via `Loader` using `Component` type? For example, this is my full source with the `Component` item and the component is missing when rendering:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 500;

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        GridLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            columns: 2
            Label {
                text:"Email:"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 80; height: 20
                border.color: "magenta"
            }
            Label {
                text: "Full Name:"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
            }
            Loader {
                id: test_item
                sourceComponent: field_template
            }
            Label {
                text: "Gender:"
            }
            RowLayout {
                Layout.minimumHeight: 20
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                RadioButton {
                    text: "Male"
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: 20
                }
                RadioButton {
                    text: "Female"
                    width: parent.width/2
                    height: 20
                }
            }
            Label {
                text: "Mobile phone:"
            }
            Rectangle {
                width: 80; height: 20
                border.color: "magenta"
            }
        }
        Row {
            Button {
                text: "Cancel"
            }
            Button {
                text: " Ok "
            }
        }
    }
    Component {
      id: field_template
      Item {
          Layout.fillWidth: true
          height: 33
          Rectangle {
              border.color: "blue"
              color: "transparent"
              anchors.left: parent.left
              anchors.right: parent.right
              anchors.top: parent.top
              anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
              anchors.rightMargin: 10

              TextEdit {
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  anchors.leftMargin: 5
                  anchors.topMargin: 3
                  anchors.rightMargin: 2
                  clip: true
                  text: "type here"
              }
          }
      }

    }
}
```

The picture of the output rendered by `qmlscene` is this:

[image]

I have correctly speecified witdht and height, why isn't the component being loaded with `Loader` ?

Comment: Look at [Layout.columnSpan](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#columnSpan-attached-prop)

Comment: Second question: your component is created, you can check it with `Component.onCompleted`. The problem is size you didn't set. I mean the `Loader`'s size. Currentrly the size is (0,0) so you just don't see the item. Try to set `Layout.fillWidth: true; Layout.preferredHeight: 33` for the `Loader` instead of `Component`'s `Item`.

Comment: For, the first question I don't think it is even possible, `qml` won't render an element with zero size, so `GridLayout` won't be considering the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question folibis is right in the comment. You just have to check the size. Here, is a working code.

```
    ...
    Item {
    Layout.fillWidth: true
    //width: 80
    height:20
        Loader {
            id: test_item
        anchors.fill: parent
            sourceComponent: field_template
        }
    } 
    ...
Component {
      id: field_template
      Item {
          Rectangle {
              border.color: "blue"
              color: "transparent"
              anchors.left: parent.left
              anchors.right: parent.right
              anchors.top: parent.top
              anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
              anchors.rightMargin: 10

              TextEdit {
                  anchors.fill: parent
                  anchors.leftMargin: 5
                  anchors.topMargin: 3
                  anchors.rightMargin: 2
                  clip: true
                  text: "type here"
              }
          }
      }
```